# Can go to the UK if I have a criminal record?

Tags: visas, uk, criminal-records, romanian-citizens

I am from Romania in 2006. I was in prison in the UK for drugs importation in 2009 and was deported. Can I go to UK and get a job?

Comment: You may have a permanent ban in place and your removal records would tell you what conditions were imposed on you as part of your conviction and deportation after confinement.

Answer (score 2):

**Not** without the help of a competent lawyer. After having criminal record in the U.K. and a subsequent deportation, any generic advice is not going to help you at all.